# How to npm install from local bitbucket?

Tags: git, bitbucket, npm-install, bitbucket-server

I have a local bitbucket server git.mydomain.com 
I can access the repository from SourceTree and do clone I can see the repo is:
http://hadar.m@git.mydomain.com:7990/scm/st/my-project.git

I have another projects I want to add package "my-project" as a dependency to it, so in the packages.json file I write

```
"dependencies": {
"@angular/common": "~2.1.0",
[... all other deps ... ],
"my-lib": "http://hadar.m@git.mydomain.com:7990/scm/st/my-project.git " }
```

as I run npm install command I get error : " fetch failed with status code 401" for this package . I've read I need to access via git+ssh and did so enabled it inside the Bitbucket admin . I've changed the packages.json to :

```
"my-lib": "git+ssh://hadar.m@git.mydomain.com:7999/scm/st/my-project.git#master"
```

the port changed to 7999 from 7990 , still error is now :

> Could not read from remote repository.
>   Please make sure you have the correct access rights

What am I doing wrong / What is the correct way to do so ?

edit:
I've created an access key in the server , after it I add this access key to the repository with read access, label : "hadar@mydomain.com" key:"[...access-key...]"
now I don't know how to construct the url to install the package.

Comment: how do you authenticate at this repository? ssh public key? user name and password?

Comment: user name and password

Comment: Is your login `hadar.m`? can you try using `hadar.m:your_password_here@git.mydomain.com:7990` as your URL to see if it works?

Comment: error on last attempt: Error: fetch failed with status code 504

Comment: How do you authenticate at all, then?

Comment: I can clone the repo pull and push commits with SourceTree installed on my local wondows machine which I've logged into with user password (hadar.m/my-pass) , the repository is in a server "git.mydomain.com" installed bitbucket .

Comment: I've updated the question with new info regarding ssh access key to repository.